# SproutForms Problem Getting Update Feed

Tags: plugin-sproutforms, plugin-sproutemail

I noticed this morning a deprecation error popped up for SproutForms.  I have version 2.2.2 (which I believe is the latest).  Here's the deprecation error:

Message
PathService::setTemplatesPath() has been deprecated. Use TemplatesService::setTemplatesPath() or TemplatesService::setTemplateMode() instead.

Origin
/home/xxx.com/craft/app/services/PathService.php (321)

I also am showing this in my craft error log:

Level   error
Category    application
Message There was a problem getting the update feed for “Web Forms”, so it was skipped: [curl] 35: [url] https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/releases.json

Answer (score 1):

These two items are unrelated.

First, there's no need to worry about the deprecation errors.  We actively maintain our plugins and will have them resolved before they should have any effect on general use of our plugins. We've made a feature request to Craft to consider to [reduce the prominence of the deprecation message](http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/13280283-deprecations-errors-shouldn-t-alarm-all-users-who), as it generally just causes unneeded alarm.

Second, the releases message is probably due to us currently having an SNI SSL certificate installed and some older server configurations choke because they don't know how to deal with them. The error probably indicates that you may be running fairly old software on your server.

If you're curious, I was told by Craft support:

> Technically there are 3 things a server needs for it to be able to
>   recognize SNI SSL certs.
>
> 1) Using a version of cURL that supports it, at least 7.18.1 (8 years
>   old: https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html)
>
> 2) Using a version of cURL compiled against a library that supports
>   SNI, e.g. OpenSSL 0.9.8j (depending on the compilation options some
>   older versions. 7 years old:
>   https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html)
>
> 3) Using TLS 1.0 at least (not SSLv3)

Comment: ohh great nice work i wasn't know about this information ago. thanks for informing.i think this information is very good for the forum user.